# Zoho CRM issue creating a function to update a field when another field gets updated

Tags: zoho, zoho-deluge

I tried to create a function in Zoho CRM to update Rate_Change_Approval field if there is any updates happens to Fees and Fees_Rate Fields gets updated to be less than 2%
so, I wrote the following script but it is not working and I am getting the following error "Error occurred while performing this action".

```
Fees = "Fees";
Fees_Rates = "Fees_Rates"; // Corrected variable name
Rate_Change_Approval = "Rate_Change_Approval";

// Assuming you have functions to retrieve values and update records in your Deluge environment

fees = getFieldValue(Fees);
fees_rates = getFieldValue(Fees_Rates);
rate_change_approval = getFieldValue(Rate_Change_Approval);

if (toNumber(Fees) < 2 && toNumber(Fees_Rates) < 2) {
    if (toText(Rate_Change_Approval) != "Pending Approval") {
        update_rate_approval = zoho.crm.updateRecord("Accounts", Rate_Change_Approval, {"Rate_Change_Approval": "Pending Approval"});
        info update_rate_approval;
    }
}
```

Any idea how to get this fixed.

what I am expecting is the Rate_Change_Approval to be changed to "Pending Approval" once Fees and Fees_Rates fields to be updated to less than 2%

Comment: in this part `fees = getFieldValue(Fees);
fees_rates = getFieldValue(Fees_Rates);
rate_change_approval = getFieldValue(Rate_Change_Approval);`, what are the result of these ?